# Using networkx graph algorithms without constructing the graph

Tags: networkx, graph-algorithm

The python `networkx` library has many useful graph algorithms, but they require to construct a `networkx.Graph`, which may be wasteful. As an example, suppose I have a map stored in a large 2-dimensional array, where each cell represents either a "road" or a "block". I want to find the shortest path between two road cells. I can construct a `networkx.Graph` by adding each road cell as a vertex, and adding an edge between each two road cells that are adjacent on the map, and then run `networkx.shortest_path(G, source, target)`. But if the map is large, this might waste a lot of memory.

Is there a way to construct a "virtual graph", that only returns vertices when they are needed for the algorithm (e.g. when the algorithm asks for neighbors of a given vertex), so that I can `shortest_path` without converting my entire map into a graph?

Comment: [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path.html) might be an option for your use case

Comment: The best way I can think of to do this would be to generate your own graph class that tries to mimic a networkx graph.  So your custom class would have to take in the data set you have and then have a way to find all the neighbors when asked for them, as well as whatever other data the shortest_path algorithms ask for.